# JSON interface problem

Tags: solidity, web3js, solc

I'm wondering why I still get

> "Error: You must provide the json interface of the contract when
> instantiating a contract object."

I've tried plenty of solution from this community but they don't work for me

When I trie to console.log(compiledFactory.abi) it said **"Undefined"**

this is my **compile.js**

```
const path = require("path");
const solc = require("solc");
const fs = require("fs-extra");

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "build");
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const campaignPath = path.resolve(__dirname, "contracts", "Campaign.sol");
const source = fs.readFileSync(campaignPath, "utf8");

var input = {
  language: "Solidity",
  sources: {
    "Campaign.sol": {
      content: source,
    },
  },
  settings: {
    outputSelection: {
      "*": {
        "*": ["*"],
      },
    },
  },
};

const output = JSON.parse(solc.compile(JSON.stringify(input)));

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

if (output.errors) {
  output.errors.forEach((err) => {
    console.log(err.formattedMessage);
  });
} else {
  const contracts = output.contracts["Campaign.sol"];
  for (let contractName in contracts) {
    const contract = contracts[contractName];
    fs.writeFileSync(
      path.resolve(buildPath, `${contractName}.json`),
      JSON.stringify(contract.abi, null, 2),
      "utf8"
    );
  }
}
```

**deploy.js**

```
require("dotenv").config({ path: "../.env" });

const HDWalletProvider = require("truffle-hdwallet-provider");
const Web3 = require("web3");
const compiledFactory = require("./build/CampaignFactory.json");

const provider = new HDWalletProvider(
  process.env.WALLET_MNEMONIC,
  process.env.INFURA_ENDPOINT
);
const web3 = new Web3(provider);

const deploy = async () => {
  const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
  console.log("Attempting to deploy using account " + accounts[0]);

  const txn = await new web3.eth.Contract(compiledFactory.abi)
    .deploy({ data: "0x" + compiledFactory.evm.bytecode.object })
    .send({ from: accounts[0] });

  console.log("Contract is at " + txn.options.address);
};

deploy();
```

I've also tried to change for loop in compile.js

```
fs.outputJSONSync(
   path.resolve(buildPath, "CampaignABI.json"),
   contract.abi
 );

 fs.outputJSONSync(
   path.resolve(buildPath, "CampaignByteCode.json"),
   contract.evm.bytecode.object
// );
```

Comment: did you solve the problem??? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: Yes man I'll show you the code.